# Matrix ring over a ring

Tags: ring-theory

Let $k$ a ring with $1\neq{0}$.

Wich is the center of $M_n(k)$?

I'm suppose that $Z(M_n(k))=\{r\cdot{Id} \ : \ r\in{Z(k)} \}$

Is correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You suppose right. Here is a hint on how to proceed:

Take $A\in Z(M_n(k))$. Take the matrix $E_{ij}$ that has all entries zero except for a $1$ in the $ij$-th entry. Now consider what $AE_{ij}=E_{ij}A$ implies.